# System.InvalidOperationException: Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(SerialNumbers)' because it has no primary key

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, linq

Currently, I am attempting to use LINQ to connect to a third-party Database to add values to a table that holds serial numbers. However, when I attempt to run my program, the error that is the question title will pop up.

Currently, the program fails on this command:

```
string STRout = foo.AccountInfo(email, serialNum, "TEST2");
```

Going into the accountInfo method, the line that calls the serialNumber method is the following (its current placement is for testing purposes):

```
this.newSerialNumber(serialNum);
```

And finally, the newSerialNumber method reads as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
    public bool newSerialNumber(string serialNum)
    {
        SerialNumbers new_SN = new SerialNumbers();
        //serialNumber is the primary key in the SerialNumbers table
        new_SN.SerialNumber = serialNum;
        new_SN.Count = 1;
        linqQueries.SerialNumbers.InsertOnSubmit(new_SN);

        linqQueries.SubmitChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

This code is derived from already-working code, which reads as follows:

```
[WebMethod]    
public bool CustomerInfo(string DealershipName, string DealershipEmail, string DealershipAddress, string Name, string DealershipNumber, string DealershipPhone, string serialNumber, string registrationNum)
    {
        //Add the new customer to the table
        CustomerInformation newCustomer = new CustomerInformation();
        newCustomer.DealershipName = DealershipName;
        newCustomer.DealershipEmail = DealershipEmail;
        newCustomer.DealershipAddress = DealershipAddress;
        newCustomer.Name = Name;
        newCustomer.DealershipNumber = DealershipNumber;
        newCustomer.DealershipPhone = DealershipPhone;
        linqQueries.CustomerInformations.InsertOnSubmit(newCustomer);

        linqQueries.SubmitChanges();
        //string activateCode = getActivation(registrationNum);

        CustomerAccount newAccount = new CustomerAccount();
        newAccount.SerialNumber = serialNumber;
        newAccount.DealershipEmail = DealershipEmail;
        newAccount.RegistrationNumber = registrationNum;
        newAccount.CustomerInformation = newCustomer;
        linqQueries.CustomerAccounts.InsertOnSubmit(newAccount);

        linqQueries.SubmitChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

In addition to the serialNumber value being the primary key in the SerialNumbers table, it is also listed as a unique value.

Am I missing something, or is there some sort of workaround to this exception that I'm unaware of in this case?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Figured out the answer. Turns out that the program didn't identify SerialNumber as being a primary key the whole time. After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1121013/5463848) answer again, I decided to look for "IsPrimaryKey" in the solution. As it turns out, there was a file that I was missing completely in the solution that deals with the tables on the database. The SerialNumbers table code looked like the following:

```
<Table Name="dbo.SerialNumbers" Member="SerialNumbers">
<Type Name="SerialNumbers">
  <Column Member="SerialNumber" Type="System.String" CanBeNull="false" />
  <Column Member="Count" Type="int" CanBeNull="false" />
</Type>
```

After I noticed this, the solution became obvious. The line

```
<Column Member="SerialNumber" Type="System.String" CanBeNull="false" />
```

should have been

```
 <Column Member="SerialNumber" Type="System.String" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
```

This quick change fixed the problem.

P.S. When working with a third-party database, make sure to keep your dll files on the database up to date! Failing to do so may cause the program to not run as intended.