# c# program trying to put data from Excel in to SQL database

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my c# program trying to put data from Excel in to SQL database.the error that will come up :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Can't perform Create, Update, or
>   Delete operations on 'Table(TableOption)' because it has no primary
>   key.'

I'm a new programmer in C#

here is the program

```
// Load excel data in to sql database
    private void BtnRefreshDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    OpenFileDialog ope = new OpenFileDialog();
        //ope.Filter = "Excel File| *.xls ";
        if (ope.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(ope.FileName, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

        LinqToEntermedDatabaseDataContext conn = new LinqToEntermedDatabaseDataContext();
     // System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(storarge="Artikel",DbType="uniquIdentifier NOT NULL",IsPrimaryKey=true) volgens voorbeeld website stackoverflow
        foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {   
                TableOption addtable = new TableOption()
                {                        
                    Artikel = Convert.ToString(dr[0]),
                    Discription = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
                    Extra1 = Convert.ToString(dr[2]),
                    Extra2 = Convert.ToString(dr[3]),
                    Kosts = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[4])

                };
                conn.TableOptions.InsertOnSubmit(addtable);

            }

            conn.SubmitChanges();
            excelReader.Close();
            stream.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Database ok");
        }

    }
```

Comment: what library are you using to deal with excel?

Comment: This similar issue may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737850/cant-perform-create-update-or-delete-operations-on-table-because-it-has-no-pri. Note that your `TableOption` class may requires `[Column(IsPrimaryKey=true)]` attribute annotation here.

Comment: The problem is you've got a table with no primary key and you arent manually writing SQL updates, if you were you could just dump the lines into a table, but the way you're doing it, you need to have defined a primary key.. which is why it says to do just that.

Comment: in my table is a primary key, where and how must i put it in my code? The Libary im using is found on www.exceldatareader.codeplex.com